# How to do pivot_table in dask with aggfunc 'min'?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to create a pivot table in either pandas or dask, but ofcourse I get a memory error in pandas. That's why I want to use dask, because I want to work with even larger files possibly.

In pandas I did this:

```
df =df.pivot_table(values="A", index="B", columns="C", aggfunc=np.min)
```

But it is not possible to use `np.min` in Dask. Is there some other clever way to do it with Dask?

Comment: No, only count, sum and mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Dask dataframe raises the following error

```
ValueError("aggfunc must be either 'mean', 'sum' or 'count'")
```

Perhaps you should submit a feature request?  https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

Comment: Yeah, I hoped their would be a way around. But a feature request is a good idea! Thanks!

Comment: Still not implemented. Maybe some technical problems with this feature?